# How do you unmarshal a JSON object to a Golang struct when the JSON field key is a date?

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have the following JSON response. What would be the best way to unmarshal this into a Golang struct? The JSON to Golang autogenerated struct is saying the named properties of the struct should be 20210712, 20210711, 20210710, etc. but that won't work because the struct field will be different as the dates change in the future. What would be the best way to do this dynamically?

```
{
  "data": {
    "2021-07-12": {
      "Neutral": 3,
      "Positive": 4,
      "Negative": 4
    },
    "2021-07-11": {
      "Neutral": 0,
      "Positive": 1,
      "Negative": 4
    },
    "2021-07-10": {
      "Neutral": 0,
      "Positive": 0,
      "Negative": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a map:

```
type Item struct {
   Neutral int
   Positive int
   Negative int
}

type Data struct {
  Data map[string]Item `json:"data"`
}
```

When you unmarshal, you can use `data.Data["2021-07-11"]`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the input from Burak Serdar ,I created a simple program for your scenario as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Item struct {
    Neutral  int
    Positive int
    Negative int
}

type Data struct {
    Data map[string]Item `json:"data"`
}

func main() {

    var resData Data

    var data = []byte(`{
   "data":{
      "2021-07-12":{
         "Neutral":3,
         "Positive":4,
         "Negative":4
      },
      "2021-07-11":{
         "Neutral":0,
         "Positive":1,
         "Negative":4
      },
      "2021-07-10":{
         "Neutral":0,
         "Positive":0,
         "Negative":3
      }
   }
}`)

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &resData); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resData)
    fmt.Println(resData.Data["2021-07-10"])

}
```

Output:

```
{map[2021-07-10:{0 0 3} 2021-07-11:{0 1 4} 2021-07-12:{3 4 4}]}
{0 0 3}
```